# %arm in RPM spec file

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am building an RPM from source tarball, patches, and a .spec file. I am doing so to add my platform-specific patch.

I have read the given .spec file, and got notice that there are lines such as:

```
%ifarch %{arm}
```

When I saw similar lines like that, I could sometimes see a definition, for example, as follows:

```
%global shared 0
```

Later on, %shared is used as 0. However, I could not find the definition of %arm. I guessed that it might be pre-defined, or defined somewhere else (system-wide?).

What does the %arm variable mean in a .spec file? If it is pre-defined, where is the definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in `/usr/lib/rpm/macros`, `arm` is defined as a list of possible ARM architectures. So that macro is saying "if the target architecture matches *any* of these, do this..."

Answer (score 0):

the %{arm} is just a RPM macro, like all the other RPM macros.

It expands out to some sort of actual value, to find that value, run the command

```
rpm --eval %{arm}
```

On my system that expands to

```
armv3l armv4b armv4l armv4tl armv5tl armv5tel armv5tejl armv6l armv6hl armv7l armv7hl armv7hnl
```

Which appears to be all of the supported arm architectures my development environment supports.